# Connecting a DVD/CDROM reader through USB OTG

Tags: hardware, video, usb-on-the-go, android-device-manager, compatibility

can CDROM/DVD readers be recognized and managed as standard USB mass storage?

Does Android include drivers or libraries to read this quite standard hardware?

Are drivers or root required?
Any tip about using on android TVS?

I plugged an external DVD player with external power supply to an Android TV through OTG.  Drive/media was not recognized, ghost commander or VLC didn't detect the device.